# Decorator Design Pattern, Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, design-patterns, decorator

I want to implement the Decorator design pattern. However, my code gives me `Segmentation fault` error. I tried to compile it using the `-g` flag and then check it with `gdb`. `gdb` shows only that the error is somewhere inside the `action` method, but I do not understand where and why.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class CComponent
{
protected:
    int * i_array;
    int i_size;
public:
    CComponent(int i_size)
    {
        this->i_size=i_size;
        i_array= new int[i_size];
        for(int i=0; i<i_size; i++)
        {
            i_array[i]=0;
        }
    }
    virtual int action() = 0;
    ~CComponent()
    {
        delete i_array;
    }
    int get_i_size()
    {
        return i_size;
    }
    int get_array_at(int index)
    {
        return i_array[index];
    }
};

class CConcreteCComponent : public CComponent
{

public:

    CConcreteCComponent(int i_size) : CComponent(i_size) { }

    int action()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<i_size; i++)
        {
            i_array[i] = rand() % 100;
            cout<< i_array[i] << " " << endl;
        }
        return 0;
    }
};

class Decorator : public CComponent
{
protected:
    CComponent * c;
public:
    Decorator(int i_size) : CComponent(i_size)
    {
        c = new CConcreteCComponent(100);
    }
    int action()
    {
        return c->action();
    }
};

class CConcreteDecorator3 : public Decorator
{

public:
    CConcreteDecorator3(int i_size) : Decorator(i_size)
    {
    }

    int action()
    {
        int w = action();
        for(int i=0; i<c->get_i_size(); i++)
            if(c->get_array_at(i) % 2 == 0)
                return w;
        return w + 50;
    }
};

class CConcreteDecorator1 : public Decorator
{
public:
    CConcreteDecorator1(int i_size) : Decorator(i_size)
    {
    }

    int action()
    {
        int w = action();

        if(c->get_array_at(0) == 0 && c->get_array_at(i_size -1) == 0)
            return w + 100;
        return w;

    }

};

class CConcreteDecorator2 : public Decorator
{
public:
    CConcreteDecorator2(int i_size) : Decorator(i_size)
    {
    }

    int action()
    {
        int w = action();

        if(c->get_i_size() > 7)
            return w + 150;
        return w;
    }

};

int main()
{
    Decorator * d = new CConcreteDecorator3(100);
    Decorator * d2 = new CConcreteDecorator1(100);
    Decorator * d3 = new CConcreteDecorator2(100);
    int res;

    res = d->action();
    cout << "res :" << res << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen by calling `action()` inside `action()`?

Comment: When you step with the debugger line by line, what did you observe?

Comment: Aside:  If you ever copy or assign a `CComponent` object you will will copy the `i_array` pointer, and then delete it twice.  If you need a destructor, you need a copy constructor and a copy assignment operator too.  (See [The Rule of Three](https://www.google.ch/search?q=rule+of+three+C%2B%2B)).  Alternatively, if you replace `i_array` with `std::vector<int> i_array`, you don't have to worry about memory management.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is an infinite recusion.

In *CConcreteDecorator3* in *action* method instead of:

```
int w = action();
```

You should probably use:

```
int w = Decorator::action();
```

Comment: Does it mean that without it I had a recursion no matter that I did not want to have recursion?

Comment: @mirx Basically, compiler doesn't know what you want :) It just looks for an appropriate function to call. If you do not specify where to look for the function, it sees the same action method and recursive call happens.

Comment: Ok now I understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Furthermore...

1. Your Decorator class leaks. You have no destructor with a delete.
2. It is considered good practice to use a `std::vector<int>` instead `int *` i_array and a std::unique_ptr for `CComponent * c;` Dont bother using new/delete unless you cannot avoid it.
3. Your CComponent needs a virtual destructor. You'll find a lot of explanations if you google polymorphism and virtual destructor.